# Matlab workspace window is not showing variables

Tags: matlab, workspace

I am using lastest Matlab 7.13 R2011b release.
I could not find solution on the web. My workspace is not showing variables.
Please suggest a solution how to fix it.

And I've read the similar topic about it, the guy has upgraded mathlab to R2011a, but I'm using the latest one

I am assigning variables from command line 
example:

```
>> a = 2
a =
     2
>> b = 3
b =
     3
>> c = a+b
c =
     5
```

And there are no variables in Workspace windows.

When I Try to assign variables from workspace window, I click 'New', it says:

```
 Undefined function 'workspacefunc' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I am using Windows 7 / x64

I know about `who` and `whos` command, but shouldn't it produce my variables to workspace?

Thanks to all, solved by installing java JDK SE 7u2

Comment: can you post a test code? like 3 lines?

Comment: here is the 3 lines of test code:a=2
b=3
c=a+b

Comment: does it produce to workspace ? as I mentioned I am using R2011b release

Comment: when you type this in workspace, dont you get C=5 at the end. Your original post show 5. I am not sure what the problem is

Comment: I am using command line to inpute 3 lines of code, but I see no variables in my Workspace window

Comment: @mydreamadsl: Just to clarify, do you assign the variables in the matlab command window?

Comment: Yes i am using command window to assign variables, and when i try assign from workspace it says Undefined function 'workspacefunc' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: type `who` and it will give you variable that are presently used or available. There is also a `whos` command I guess. Check the history and see if your variable exists.

Comment: and I know about who and whos command, but shouldn't it produce to what i assigned from command line to workspace?

Comment: if a variable has a value and it exists. If you type it and enter, it will show the value stored in that variable.

Comment: I know, and I know there exist clear command. But still It doesn't produce my variables to Workspace

Comment: I believe it's a problem with MATLAB installation, probably related to java. Have you tried to restart MATLAB? Reinstall MATLAB?

Comment: Tried to restart or reinstall? What happens if you type in command line `openvar c`?

Comment: Show the output of commands: `which workspacefunc` and `path`. I think your path variable is broken.

Comment: Since I don't now how you solved the problem I'll not make an answer from my comments. But I would recommend you to post an answer with the solution. That might be helpful for others. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for everyone's effort

Comment: @mydreamadsl: Could you explain in a few words what you did to fix the problem. How did you fix the "java problem"?

Comment: @mydreamadsl: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. Using this command `restoredefaultpath;matlabrc` solved my problem.

UPDATE:
 my solution is temporal solution, but you can find consistent solution for this problem here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102432-why-do-i-receive-a-warning-regarding-missing-pathdef-m-when-starting-matlab-7-14-r2012a

Comment: This helped me on MATLAB 2015a, Thanks! However, it should be mentioned that this fix requires administrator privileges.